# HTML - Alert Box when loading page

Tags: javascript, html, alert, messagebox

i'm using HTML code and i wan't to show un Alert Message or alert box, i don't know what it is called, but a message with a "OK" button.

i want to show this alert when the page is loaded.

How do i do this?

And how to do this with a title in the Alert box?

Do I need JavaScript? if no, How to do this without javascript?

Jonathan

Comment: you need javascript. look for an alert button.

Answer (score 18):

Yes you need javascript.  The simplest way is to just put this at the bottom of your HTML page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
alert("Hello world");
</script>
```

There are more preferred methods, like using jQuery's ready function, but this method will work.

Comment: Thanks, but do you know how to set a title for the alert message box?

Comment: It can't be done with the standard alert box in javascript.  You could use a more complex DHTML solution to accomplish something like that.  Using something like what "Shanimal" suggested could do that.

Answer (score 4):

you need a tiny bit of Javascript.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function(){ 
                alert("Hi there");
                }
</script>
```

This is only slightly different from Adam's answer.  The effective difference is that this one alerts when the browser considers the page fully loaded, while Adam's alerts when the browser scans part the `<script>` tag in the text.  The difference is with, for example, images, which may continue loading in parallel for a while.

Comment: Thanks, but do you know how to set a title for the alert message box?

Comment: No, the box you get from alert is defined by the browser.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a variety of methods, one uses Javascript window.onload function in a simple function call from a script or from the body as in the solutions above, you can also use jQuery to do this but its just a modification of Javascript...Just add Jquery to your header by pasting

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

to your head section and open another script tag where you display the alert when the DOM is ready i.e. `

```
<script>
    $("document").ready( function () {
        alert("Hello, world");
    }); 
</script>
```

`

This uses Jquery to run the function but since jQuery is a Javascript framework it contains Javascript code hence the Javascript alert function..hope this helps...

Answer (score 3):

If you use jqueryui (or another toolset) this is the way you do it

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jeLhJ

**html**

```
<div id="hw" title="Empty the recycle bin?">The new way</div>
```

**javascript**

```
$('#hw').dialog({
    close:function(){
        alert('the old way')
    }
})
```

**UPDATE : how to include jqueryui by pointing to cdn**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, but do you know how to set a title for the alert message box?

Comment: Keep in mind, with this solution you need to include the JQuery, JQuery UI, and JQuery UI Theme on your page.  It is far more complicated than using a simple Javascript alert box, but you should be able to at least change the title (and of course it looks really cool).

Comment: There are other libraries as well besides jqueryui

Comment: Heres the documentation for http://jqueryui.com/dialog  Also don't forget you can use cdnjs or some other CDN for jqueryui code and css

Comment: I updated the codepen and the code above to include the title

Answer (score 2):

For making alert just put below javascript code in footer.

```
<script> 
 $(document).ready(function(){
    alert('Hi');
 });
</script>
```

You need to also load jquery min file.
Please insert this script in header.

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js'></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.alert("My name is George. Welcome!")
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script> 
    $(document).ready(function(){
        alert('Hi');
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){      
  alert();
     $('#rep‌​ortVariablesTable tbody').append( '<tr><td>lll</td><td>lll</td></tr>');
});
```